# Convert UTF-8 to CP1252 ruby 2.2

Tags: ruby, utf-8

How to keep all characters converting from UTF-8 to CP1252 on ruby 2.2

this code:

```
file = 'd:/1 descrição.txt'
puts file.encode('cp1252')
```

Give this error:

```
`encode': U+0327 to WINDOWS-1252 in conversion from UTF-8 to WINDOWS-1252 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
```

My application need to be cp1252, but I can't find any way to keep all the characters.

I can't replace this characters, because later I will use this info to read the file from file system.

```
puts file.encode('cp1252', undef: :replace, replace: '')
> d:/1 descricao.txt
```

ps: It is a ruby script not a ruby on rails application

Comment: I'm using Ruby 2.3 and your code produces no errors. Are you sure that string is correct and actually UTF-8 in your source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UTF-8 covers the entire range of unicode, but CP1252 only includes a subset of them. Obviously this means that there are characters that can be encoded in UTF-8 but not in CP1252. This is the problem you are facing.

In your example it *looks* like the string only contains characters that should work in CP1252, but clearly it doesn’t.

The character in the error message, [U+0327](http://www.charbase.com/0327-unicode-combining-cedilla) is a [*combining character*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), and is not representable in CP1252. It combines with the preceding `c` to produce `ç`. `ç` can also be represented as a *single* character ([U+00E7](http://www.charbase.com/00e7-unicode-latin-small-letter-c-with-cedilla)), which *is* representable in CP1252.

One option might be [*normalisation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization), which will convert the string into a form that is representable in CP1252.

```
file = 'd:/1 descrição.txt'.unicode_normalize(:nfc)
puts file.encode('cp1252')
```

(It appears that Stack Overflow is normalizing the string when displaying your question, which is probably why copying the code from the question and running it doesn’t produce any errors.)

This will avoid the error, but note that it is not necessarily possible to reverse the process to get the original string unless the original is in a known normalized form already.